# How to handle blender's mirror modifier in libgdx

Tags: libgdx, blender, mirror

In blender I created a human body using the mirror modifier, so that i had only to model half of the body and the other half would mirror automatically.

However, when I export that model and show in with libgdx, I see only that half. The mirror is missing. And I want to add animations like walking running. So probably, I have to replace the mirror modifier by actual mesh? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blender's modifiers are programmed to modify objects in certain ways, don't expect any of them to be available outside of blender. You should always apply any modifiers before trying to share data with other programs.

Every modifier in blender has an apply button that will permanently alter the object to match what the modifier generates.

[image]

If you are using several modifiers you may want to use "Convert to Mesh" (press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>). While this sounds odd when you already have a mesh object, it will apply all modifiers on the object.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should apply your modifieres during the export.

[image: Apply Modifieres during export step]

This is the cleanest way cause you don't have to apply all modifieres on every development step of your mesh.

Comment: That is helpful but not all exporters include this option, although the most common ones do appear to.

Comment: this is the view of the fbx exporter which is the most supported format on all engines/frameworks i know so far. Haven't checked alternate export dialogs. It is a blender function, rather independent of the export format.